Understanding Remark I.12.14(c) from Amann Escher Analysis I on certain arithmetic sequences
The remark mentioned in the title reads as below. My bracketed comments are for extra context. I have also labelled each sentence so that I can refer to it in my questions.

(1) A function $f \in E^\Bbb N$ [$E$ is a vector space over the field $\Bbb K := \Bbb R, \Bbb C$] is called an arithmetic sequence of order $k ∈ \Bbb N^\times$ [$\Bbb N^\times := \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$] if $\Delta^k f$ is constant, that is, if $\Delta^{k+1} f = 0$.


(2) From (12.15) and Remark 8.19(c), it follows that, for each polynomial $p \in \Bbb K_k[X]$, each $h \in \Bbb K^\times$, and each $x_0 \in \Bbb K$, the function $\Bbb N \to \Bbb K, n \mapsto p(x_0 + hn)$ is an arithmetic sequence of order $k$.


(3) In particular, for each $k \in \Bbb N$, the ‘power sequence’ $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$, $n \mapsto n^k$ is an arithmetic sequence of order k.

In what follows I play a little fast and loose with the difference between polynomials and their range in the space of functions $\Bbb K^\Bbb K$, but hopefully that confusion can be swept aside.
For the key context, I give Proposition 12.13 which contains the formula (12.15) alluded to:

12.13 Proposition The Newton interpolation polynomial for a function $f$ and equally
spaced points $x_j :=x_0 +jh, 0\leq j\leq m$ has the form
$$N_m[f; x_0; h] = \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{\Delta^j_hf(x_0)}{j!} \prod_{k=0}^{j-1} (X − x_k),  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,    (12.15)$$
where $\Delta_h \in $ End $\Bbb K^\Bbb K$ is defined by $\Delta_h f (x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$.

Remark 8.19(c) is nothing more than the claim that two polynomials of degree at most $K$ which are equal at $k+1$ points are in fact equal.

Remark 8.19(c) If $p$ and $q$ are polynomials over [a field] $K$ of degree at most n such that $p(a_i) = q(a_i)$ for some distinct $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_{n+1} \in K$, then $p = q$ (identity theorem for polynomials).

My questions for some of the labelled sentence above are as below:
(2a) How does this follow? The way the author is arguing seems to be that since a polynomial of degree $k$ equals its Newton polynomial of that same degree (by Proposition 8.19(c)), it follows that $p(x_0 + nh) = N_k[p;x_0;h](x_0 + nh)$ and then I suspect I should be able to use (12.15) pictured above to calculate out $N_k[p;x_0;h](x_0 + nh)$ on the RHS, and then somehow observe that the sequence so obtained is an arithmetic sequence of order $k$? I am getting lost in the morass of calculations when doing this, so perhaps I am not even right with the idea for the proof.
(2b) Amann Escher takes great pride in doing most things in great generality. I was therefore surprised that the entire section proceeded in the context of the reals or complex numbers ($\Bbb K$) rather than an arbitrary field $K$. I didn't notice anywhere that anything other than general field properties were used, so if anyone knows why the restriction I would greatly appreciate it.
(3) Given that (2) is dealt with, how does this follow? Does one simply use the polynomial $p = X^k$, $x_0 = 0$, $h =1$?

Let me add that, if it feels like I am missing including certain information, please let me know and I'd be happy to supply it.

As for why the field restrictions, it’s because of all the divisions being performed. Also, the identification of polynomials with the associated functions. It’s just convenient to work in a field of characteristic $0$ (pretty sure this suffices, but I only had a cursory look at things)… so now my question would be whether or not they introduced the notion of characteristic of a field? If not, it just makes sense to restrict to the case of reals/complex for simplicity.

@peek-a-boo Thanks for the comment :) Why would divisions being present necessitate choosing specific fields when division is perfectly well-defined in any field? As for the relationship to polynomials, they did discuss that polynomials over infinite fields have a the standard homorphism actually as an injection into $K^K$, whereas this is not the case for finite fields, but (a) I'm not sure if that's what you're talking about and (b) I'm not sure where that hypothesis slips in.

There are divisions by $j!$. In a finite field this could be $0$. For example in a field of characteristic $2$, we have $2!=2=0$. But ok right now I’m still not a 100% sure whether this is strictly necessary or if there’s some way to rephrase the statement to avoid division by these factorials. Anyway for the other questions, I might answer them later (if no one else does in the meantime).

Oy, of course! That makes sense...thanks very much @peek-a-boo !

(2a) I think that the author wants you to consider $N_{k+1}[p;x_0;h]$, that has degree less than or equal to $k+1$, and which is equal to $p$ on $k+2$ different points. So that $N_{k+1}[p;x_0;h]$ is equal to $p$ (and to $N_{k}[p;x_0;h]$ has you pointed out), by the remark. This implies that the last term in the sum of $N_{k+1}[p;x_0;h]$ is zero (the only one of degree k+1). So $\Delta^{k+1}_h p(x_0) = 0$.
You can do the same, starting with point $x_1=x_0+h$ and the result for $N_{k+1}[p;x_1;h]$ is again true : $\Delta^{k+1}_h p(x_1) = 0$. In general you have $N_{k+1}[p;x_m;h]=p$ and $\Delta^{k+1}_h p(x_m) = 0$ for $x_m=x_0+mh$ and $m \in \Bbb N$.
Therefore $h^{k+1} \times \Delta^{k+1}_h p(x_m)=0$ for each $m \in \Bbb N$, and finally you get $\Delta^{k+1} p = 0$ which means $\Delta^{k} p$ is constant (and equal to the leading coefficient of $p$) that is the sequence is arithmetic of order (precisely) $k$.
(2b) I would say that you need $k+2$ (it will be enough $k+1$ points, if you work directly with $N_{k}[p;x_m;h]$ without using $N_{k+1}[p;x_m;h]$) different points in the prime field of $\Bbb K$ to apply the preceding proof (take $x_0=0$ and $h=1$ and $k \in \Bbb N$). So you need a field of characteristic zero if you don't want any limitation on the polynomial degree of $p$.
Anyway, I believe that similar results can be proved if $\Bbb K$ has finite characteristic with some care on the degree of $p$ (you get surprising things like a sequence of the form  $n \mapsto p(0+1n)$ is periodic)
(3) Yes, use point (2) with $x_0=0$ , $h=1$ and $p=X^k$ to obtain $p(0+1n)=p(n)=n^k$.

Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!
